# Laravell 5. Вопрос связан с ролями пользователей

Tags: php, алгоритм, laravel

Есть 5 типов пользователей, идентифицируется условно по POSITION (1-5)
Имеется контроллер main. 
Вопрос: как отображать контроллер и главный экшн у всех пользователей, с условием что виды у пользователей разные, и функции.. так же меню разное.
Контроллер имеется один.
Помогите  разобраться ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1 (для минимального объема данных):**

```
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        switch($user->role){
            case 1: {
                return view('user/role1' . ,
                    ['user'=>$user]
                );
            }
            break;
            case 2: {
                return view('user/role2' . ,
                    ['user'=>$user]
                );
            }
            break;
            case 3: {
                return view('user/role3' . ,
                    ['user'=>$user]
                );
            }
            break;
            /** ... */
        );


    }
```

**Вариант 2. (для среднего объема данных):**

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    // $user->role = 1 или 2 или 3...
    $this->role . $user->role($user);        
}

public function role1(User $user)
{
    return view('user/role1' . ,
                ['user'=>$user]
            );        
}

public function role2(User $user)
{
    return view('user/role1' . ,
                ['user'=>$user]
            );        
}

public function role3(User $user)
{
    return view('user/role1' . ,
                ['user'=>$user]
            );         
}

/** ... */
```

**Вариант 3. (для большого объема данных):**

Каждая роль обрабатывается в своем контроллере.

Comment: А не могли бы прикинь вариант с модулями.

Comment: В написанном выше, конечно так можно сделать. Но будет большая путаница если я буду менять что то. Дело в том что у каждого из пользователей будут свои виджеты на экране, и у всех они разные.. В зависимости от Роли.

Comment: Ищу вариант, чтобы я смог потом без труда добавить отображение для нового типа пользователей.  Не могу сообразить

Comment: Обновил ответ. Гляньте ;)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461967  гляньте пожалуйста.