# Роли пользователей

Tags: php, laravel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется 3 типа пользователей (ролей).
В роли сотрудник имеется 2 типа отрасли работы, в каждой из них имеются типы сотрудников().

Вопрос: Как организовать такую структуру с учетом того, что у сотрудников в отрасли разные виды отображения, функционал.

Пример: У Отрасли работы 1. используются заказы на дому. И собственно отображается список заказов у сотрудников этой отрасли.
У отрасли 2 используется заказы в офисе. Ну и конечно же сотрудники этой отрасли работают именно с этими заказами.
Прошу помочь. Мысли в голове есть, но все смутно как то, изучаю laravel, да и вообще MVC и ООП не давно.

Еще один ньюанс!! Сотрудники должны иметь один контроллер: к примеру (main).
То есть, сотрудник зашедший на сайт должен видеть URL к примеру: local/main
Но при этом, исходя из вопроса выше он должен получать к примеру список заказов, исходя из типа отрасли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае, мне кажется рациональным создать отдельный контроллер для "отраслей" - т.к. это логически работа с другими данными. Внутри метода, который отвечает за данный тип сотрудника проверять, какую "отрасль работы" он выполняет и возвращать соответствующий контроллер. Код будет выглядеть так:

```
class mainController
{
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        $userMethod = 'role' . ucfirst($user->role);
        $this->$userMethod($user);
    }

    private function roleEmployee(User $user)
    {
        $branch = $user->branche; // здесь $user->branche = "отрасль работы"
        $typeOfEmployee = $user->typeOfEmployee; // Тип сотрудника
        if(class_exists($branch)){
             $brancheСontroller = new $branch();
             return $brancheСontroller->$typeOfEmployee($data); //$data - необходимые для работы $brancheСontroller-а данные
        } else {
             throw new \Exception("msg");
        }
    }
}

class SomeBrancheСontroller
{
    public function someTypeOfEmployee($data)
    {
        // some code
        return view(...);
    }

    /** ... */

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все понял. Помог!