# Проектирование. Роли. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, role

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Доброго времени суток.

Имеется 3 основные роли: **Гость**, **Сотрудник**, **Администратор**
Не буду затрагивать роли Администратора и Гостя, вся суть в роли: **Сотрудник**
Сотрудник имеет 2 направления:

**1**. Заявки на дому(обслуживание на дому)
 **2**. Заявки в мастерской

Каждая из направлений имеет типы(роли) сотрудников.
**Вопрос:**

1. Как **грамотно** составить роли сотрудников ? Какую **библиотеку** для этого
   использовать ?Как **правильнее** организовать всю эту структуру на фреймворке **laravel** ?
   **P.S.** Учитывая, что у пользователя будет **одна** учетная запись. А типов сотрудников к которому он присвоен может быть несколько. Т.е. **один сотрудник мог работать в разным типах:** как мастер по компьютерам в сервисе, так и мастер по компьютерам на дому.
   От туда напрашивается: сотрудник зашедший в приложение будет иметь возможность переключать свой тип учетной записи.
2. **Каким образом организовать переход между учетными записями** и в типе работы и в типе роли сотрудника в этом типе работы ?
   P.S. При переходе на другую(так сказать) учетную запись сотрудника он так же должен переходить на соответствующий внутренний контроллер(если таковой используется), то как фиксировать его состояние ? Наверно посредством Cookie или Session.

Все что мне приходит в голову. Так это для начала, написать с нуля свой режим ролей.

Comment: Разве вы уже не задавали в точности такой же вопрос?

Comment: Да, картинки стали красивее, но, похоже рисовать картинки вам нравится куда больше, чем программировать. Кстати, это весьма прилично оплачивается ;)

Comment: С момента последних постов вы хоть как-то продвинулись в написании кода?
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461967/ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461837

Comment: Дело в том что по мере углубление в программирование подобной архитектуры все больше и больше вопросов появляется)
По этому пытаюсь переформулировать вопрос. Даты получить обширнее ответ.

Comment: Я понял ваш предыдущий ответ. Но теперь у меня появляются другие проблемы, связаны с регистрацией роли сотрудника. А так же со сменой учетной записи

Comment: Но по скольку ответа не нахожу на свой вопрос в интернете. Я склоняюсь теперь к дублированию учетных записей. И просто програмная переавториация на нужный аккаунт. Это все, на что возможно мое воображение на эту тему:(

Comment: Да, и библиотек нужных про роли найти не могу. Пользуюсь entrust. Но толку. Я конечно определяю роли главные. А вот как определять и учитывать типы работ и типы сотрудников в этих работах. Не по силу мне наверно. Готовых решений просто нет

Comment: Я тогда рекомендую ставить вопрос более конкретно. Потому как в той форме, в которой вопрос есть сейчас - на него довольно сложно ответить (и это скорее будет мнение отвечающего). Пишите об одной, узкой, конкретной проблеме, которую вы решаете прямо сейчас. Ответ получите гораздо быстрее. Пользы от этого ответа сообществу будет больше.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30927/discussion-between-mr-music-and-razzwan).

Comment: "Готовых решений просто нет". Готовые решения очень редко решают вашу конкретную боль. Конечно, они нуждаются в доработке.

Comment: Я это и имел ввиду. Я понимаю что я могу переработать entrust под себя. И так же понимаю что на это уйдет как минимум пару месяцев. Так как я знаком с laravel всего пару недель

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам подойдет любой пакет, который поддерживает несколько ролей у пользователя.
Например: [**zizaco/entrust**](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#role) или [**bican/roles**](https://github.com/romanbican/roles). Главное, правильно его использовать.

Вы неправильно определили сущности. И зациклились на этом.
Представьте, что у вас только роли.

Гость, Сотрудник, Администратор — это все глобальные роли.
Они определяют основные права. Например, Гость имеет доступ к контактной информации, Администратор к управлению пользователями, а Сотрудник к разводящей странице для всех типов мастеров.

Выездной мастер и Специалист в мастерской — это более конкретные роли для сотрудников. Каждая из них по своему расширяет доступ сотрудника к объектам в админке. Например, любой Выездной специалист имеет доступ к учетной таблице, где может отмечать время выезда и комментарии по заявке, а Сотрудник имеет доступ к сводной таблице техники, находящейся в ремонте и под его ответственностью и может выставлять статус готовности ремонта.

Мастер по компьютерам или Мастер по холодильникам — это совсем конкретные роли, которые открывают доступ к специфичным только для этих ролей возможностям.
Они могут служить чем-то вроде фильтра. Например, Мастер по холодильникам видит сводную таблицу по всем холодильникам, поступившим в мастерскую и может взять заявки из этой таблицы в работу.

Идею уловили?

---

Вам не нужно переключать учетные записи. Даже если речь идет об обращении к разным контроллерам для разных типов сотрудников. Почему бы не организовать разделение функционала для разных типов сотрудников в виде подменю или табов, элементы и содержимое которых доступны только при наличии у пользователя соответствующей роли?

Или, как вариант, почему бы не воспользоваться возможностями `QueryBuilder`?

```
$query = Order::select('name');

// Добавляем в выборку заказы типа "холодильник"
if($user->hasRole('Master A')) {
    $query->where('type', 'refrigerator');
}

// Добавляем в выборку заказы типа "телефон"
if($user->hasRole('Master B')) {
    $query->where('type', 'phone');
}

$rows = $query->get();
```

У мастера сразу две специальности? Замечательно, показывайте ему два таба с разным функционалом, содержимое которых получайте по ajax или дайте доступ к двум разным страницам или сформируйте контент заранее с помощью `QueryBuilder`, как показано выше. Если хотите, вы можете скомбинировать эти варианты.

Доступ к функционалу будет определен разрешениями, прописанными вами для ролей.
Ни в куках, ни в сессии хранить ограничения вам будет не нужно. Все будет определено на основе прав каждой роли.

Как реализовать функционал с несколькими контроллерами вам **[ответили ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462081/13336)**. Делайте выбор контроллера на основе роли пользователя.

Comment: Спасибо. Идею уловил